# ORA-01489 during materialized view creation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

I am creating a materialized view in the following way:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MY_MATVIEW
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
START WITH TO_DATE('07-04-2014 01:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') NEXT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1 + 1/24 
AS
SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_VIEW;
```

and during creation I get `"ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long"`

In MY_VIEW there are 5 columns and 1 record only such that each column in the record contains a string consisting from 5 characters at most...

What might be the problem?

Really appreciate your help!
Andrey

Comment: What is the DDL for the `MY_VIEW` view, and for the underlying table(s)?

Comment: What happens if you run `SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_VIEW;` to completion (i.e. retrieve all the records) - does it raise the same error?